# meta/prefs.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

I have a code in QtCreator in Ubuntu derived from [a mutter source](https://github.com/GNOME/mutter/blob/wip/xinput2/src/core/core.c) . But I get this error:

```
main.cpp:11: error: meta/prefs.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mutter
```

but the problem persists. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: This link https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=meta%2Fprefs.h&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any tells me that the `meta/prefs.h` can be found in package `libmuffin-dev` or `libmutter-dev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to install the developer package(s) to the library package(s) you are using.

For `libmutter` this is `libmutter-dev`.

---

From the error message you show we learn the compiler is looking for `meta/prefs.h`.
Looking for `meta/prefs.h` on your disk after installation of the relevant package you find it under `/usr/include/mutter/`.

The latter is not in the compiler's default include search path which is only `/usr/include`.

To fix this either change

```
#include <meta/prefs.h>
```

to be

```
#include <mutter/meta/prefs.h>
```

or tell the compiler to look for the file in question under `/usr/include/mutter` by adding the option `-I/usr/include/mutter`the compiler's options.

More on gcc's preprocessor option's here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

---

Btw: The error you are observing is not given by the compiler, but by the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor#C_preprocessor) run *before* the compiler.